# Query result return empty recordset while it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I try to query my SQL Server database with my NodeJS server through this function :

```
    async getData(machine, reference, startDate, endDate) {
        try {
            let request = 'EXEC ' + this.sqlConfig.database + '.dbo.getData ' + machine + ', \'' + reference + '\', \'' + startDate + '\', \'' + endDate + '\''
            let result = await sql.query(request);
            return result;
        } catch  (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    }
```

When I log `request`, I have the right query :

`EXEC PROFACE.dbo.getData 195, 28446705, '2020-08-04 05:00', '2020-08-04 21:00'`

When I log `result`, I have an empty recordset :

`Results : {"recordsets":[[]],"recordset":[],"output":{},"rowsAffected":[]}`

But when I execute the `request` query directly in my database, I have a result.

[image]

I don't have any error and the connection between the database and the NodeJs server works fine because other queries works.

Any idea where the problem might come from?

Comment: you should log the request, too

Comment: Seems like you're passing datetime values in as strings instead of datetimes. Do you get different results from your proc if you use `set dateformat mdy` and `set dateformat dmy` beforehand?

Comment: Do I have to add those lines in my proc ? Or in my request ? @AlwaysLearning

Comment: When testing from SSMS, if you `set dateformat mdy; EXEC PROFACE.dbo.getIndicators 195, 28446705, '2020-08-04 05:00', '2020-08-04 21:00'` and `set dateformat dmy; EXEC PROFACE.dbo.getIndicators 195, 28446705, '2020-08-04 05:00', '2020-08-04 21:00'` do you get two different results?

Comment: getIndicators != getData

Comment: @Turo just changed the name, same problem

Comment: @AlwaysLearning with ```set dateformat mdy```, I don't have any result, but with ```set dateformat dmy``` I get the expected result

Comment: What @AlwaysLearning is saying is that `'2020-08-04` could mean two different dates: 04-Aug-2020 or 08-Apr-2020 depending on server region settings and various other parameters.

Comment: @Alex indeed it's ambiguous !

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thank you, I added ```set dateformat dmy``` in my request in my script and it works fine now !

Comment: I suppose that's one way of fixing it. A better way would be to use parameterized queries (aka. [prepared statements](https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#prepared-statement)) so that you're passing values as native types whilst also avoiding SQL injection issues.